# How to swipe between pages while leaving some objects stationary

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I'm making a start on my new application, and I am trying to figure out the best way to go about a particular element.

Basically, I would like to have a map on a view with some text underneath and above. The user could then swipe the text at the bottom and the map would change location and then text would display information about that location.

I assume I would need to use a page control for this, but obviously I do not want the map object to move (or the text above the map), I just need the text to follow the user's swipe. Is there a way to use a page control to just scroll between text but leave the rest of the page stationary?

If not, what is the best way for me to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. Put only the labels for the text in a horizontal scroll view with paging enabled. Implement the scroll view delegate methods 
scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:, and update your map in those methods.